Is this a class of optimization problems? If so, how to proceed?
Minimize over conformable matrices $(A, B)$ a linear function of $\text{vec}(A)$ where $AB = M$ for a known matrix $M$, and both $\text{vec}(A)$ and $\text{vec}(B)$ satisfy linear constraints.
This is similar to a range of matrix factorization problems, but it's different in that it has arbitrary linear constraints for both $A$ and $B$ and I want to optimize over a function of $A$.

Too hard. A special case is when you have all matrices purely diagonal and $M$ is the zero matrix, so your constraint $AB=M$ reduces to $a_ib_i=0$ for all $i$. Adding in the linear constraint $a_i+b_i=1$ enforces binary constraints on your variables. So your class of problems is at least as hard as integer linear programs.

@Michael that is too bad. $vec(A)$ and $vec(B)$ actually satisfy separate linear constraints, but I take the broader point.

Separate linear constraints can be used to do the same thing by doubling the number of variables. Force $x_iy_i=0$, $w_iz_i=0$. Then treat $(x_i,w_i)$ as part of your A variables, $(y_i,z_i)$ as part of your B variables, and use the separate linear constraints $x_i+w_i=1$ and $y_i+z_i=1$. It means $x_i\in{0,1}$.

Here are details to show that if you can solve your general problem, even with separate linear constraints enforced across the $A$ and $B$ variables, then you can solve general integer linear programs.
Setup: Given constant vectors $c, d, r$ and matrices $M$, $H$ of appropriate size. Decision variables $x=(x_1, ..., x_n)$.
ILP:
Minimize: $c^{\top}x$
Subject to:
\begin{align}
&Mx\leq d\\
&Hx=r\\
&x_i\in\{0,1\} \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}
\end{align}
Transformation:
Define new variables $a=(x_1, ..., x_n, w_1, ..., w_n)$ and $b=(y_1, ..., y_n, z_1, ..., z_n)$. Define $A=Diag(a)$ and $B=Diag(b)$ (meaning that $A$ and $B$ are $2n\times 2n$ pure diagonal matrices with diagonal components given by the $a$ and $b$ vectors). New problem:
Minimize: $c^{\top}x$
Subject to:
\begin{align}
&AB=0 \quad \mbox{(where $0$ is the all zero matrix of size $2n \times 2n$)}\\
&Mx\leq d \quad \mbox{(these are separate over the $a$ variables)}\\
&Hx=r \quad \mbox{(these are separate over the $a$ variables)}\\
&x_i+w_i=1 \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\} \quad \mbox{(these are separate over the $a$ variables)}\\
&y_i+z_i=1 \quad \forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}\quad \mbox{(these are separate over the $b$ variables)}
\end{align}
Claim: If $(x,w,y,z)$ satisfies the constraints of the new problem and has objective value $c^{\top}x$, then $x$ satisfies the constraints of the ILP (and has the same objective value).  Conversely, if $x$ satisfies the constraints of the ILP and has objective value $c^{\top}x$, then $(x,w,y,z)=(x,1-x, 1-x, x)$ satisfies the constraints of the new problem (and has the same objective value).
Proof: Suppose $(x,w,y,z)$ satisfies the constraints of the new problem. Then $Mx\leq d$ and $Hx=r$, so it suffices to show $x$ is a binary vector. Fix $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$.  If $x_i=0$ we are done. Suppose $x_i\neq 0$. The constraint $AB=0$ reduces to
$$x_iy_i=0$$
$$w_iz_i=0$$
Since $x_i\neq 0$, the constraint $x_iy_i=0$ implies $y_i=0$.
The constraint $y_i+z_i=1$ implies $z_i=1$.
The constraint $w_iz_i=0$ implies $w_i=0$.
The constraint $x_i+w_i=1$ implies $x_i=1$.  So $x$ satisfies the constraints of the ILP.
Now suppose $x$ satisfies the constraints of the ILP. Then $x$ is binary-valued and so the vector $1-x$ is binary-valued. It is easy to verify that $(x,w,y,z)=(x,1-x,1-x,x)$ satisfies the constraints of the new problem.
$\Box$
It follows that the new problem is feasible if and only if the ILP is feasible.  Assuming feasibility, a solution to either problem easily gives a solution to the other. For example, if $(x^*,w^*,y^*,z^*)$ solves the new problem then $x^*$ solves the ILP.
